# remember/log changes one makes on Debian, for later use e.g. reinstall OS (not on server per se)

Tags: linux, debian

From the perspective of a new Debian user or from a fresh installation,

1. if you change Debian, for example

   - turning off a driver for touch screen
   - installing software from source
   - binding keys
   - et cetera...
2. what are the best ways to keep track of the changes?

In slightly different contexts like looking back on years of changes, it has been reported on [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/691453/whats-the-best-way-to-trace-all-the-changes-ive-made-to-my-system-files-over-t), [quora](https://www.quora.com/Which-tools-do-you-use-to-keep-track-of-all-the-changes-youve-made-when-working-on-client-projects), and [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/98sz7i/how_do_you_keep_track_of_customizations_you_made/) to do this

- manually in a text file
- in a Zim notepad
- scripted in version control / git (different approaches and scopes are suggested)
- Ansible
- metapackages for Arch Linux
- Puppet
- etckeeper
- saltstack
- SVN
- infinite bash history
- Gists
- jrnl

Comment: The question is not entirely clear in terms of what is a desired solution. (1) /var/log/dpkg.log keeps track of package installation/removal. (2) etckeeper keeps track of changes to system configuration files. (3) Key bindings are at the user level so some sort of dotfile manager like dotdrop would do. Since all three above are different levels of changes it would not be sensible to track them all with the same tool.

Comment: @Kapil I think that itself is an informative comment: different tools may be needed to track different sorts/levels of changes. Thanks.

Comment: @Kapil, did I miss levels of changes to Debian that also could be tracked?

Answer (score 0):

The DevSecOps state of art way is to treat servers like a cattle, not pets. Then the idea is to have scripts which deploy servers from stracth, and the configuration reference is the script. With such a scheme, a configuration change deploy the server again. It is a longer procedure than tweaking a configuration file, but it makes it easier to have a little configuration state you manage (your script).

Then there are multiple technologies available to setup a new server (Ansible, puppet...). They make easier to write your deployment script.

Since something can go wrong after a change, a code revision system may trace what you have changed from a version to an other (the nowadays standard is `git`, but you can have multiple integrated software based on this standard: Github, Gitlab...)

Comment: I don’t think the system in question is a server. A cattle approach is workable for an end-user system but it requires an extremely rigorous discipline...

Comment: Indeed @StephenKitt. Albeit this answer is helpful and informative to the question, I was more intending to address the use of OS on laptops, not necessarily the working of servers.